# Angular 12 Project is attempting to disable the Ivy compiler

Tags: angular, angular12

I updated angular 10 to 12 and now when i try to build it this warning is being displayed:

> Project is attempting to disable the Ivy compiler. Angular versions 12 and higher do not support the deprecated View Engine compiler for applications. The Ivy compiler will be used to build this project.

Project is attempting to disable ivy but it is using it for my project, should i disable it somehow or its is it using it because of a package and i need to find that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you commented earlier, you are using

```
"enableIvy": false
```

in your tsconfig.app.json or tsconfig.json.

That is what creates the warning. You are trying to disable Ivy, but that is not allowed in v12. You can just **remove that line**.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly check `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` files. If you have specified true or false under `angularCompilerOptions` as follows, remove
`enableIvy` related property completely.

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular versions >12 forcefully enables the Ivy compiler even though you disable it in tsconfig. Just remove {"enableIvy": false} from tsconfig to clear the warning

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, removing it from both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json is gonna work, just remove or comment the "enableIvy": false. Works for me(angular v14)